# anchor div inside another div with scrolling

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am trying to anchor a div to the bottom right corner of another div. The anchor works as long as the parent div is not scrolled. A working JSFiddle is set up [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/JananiA/ayt41bw0/). Once the div is scrolled horizontally, the re-size handle also moves.

As it can be seen here, the css for the re-size handle is anchored using the `botton` and `right` properties.

```
ui-resizable-se {
  cursor: se-resize;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
}
```

How to achieve the anchor effect after scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but if you wrap the scrollable div with a wrapper and set the wrapper to be resizable it works well enough.

```js
$("#wrapper").resizable();
```

```css
#test {
  width: calc(100% + 15px);
  height: calc(100% + 15px);
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 185px;
  height: 185px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test">
    <p> this is going to be a very long text !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to preserve the effect you wanted I set `#wrapper` to a set width and height while allowing `#test` to fill it's parent with a width and height of 100%.  To move the handle back into `#test` I set `#wrapper` to be smaller than what you had originally and made `#test` an equal amount bigger with `calc()`.  I think this gives the results you were looking for.

Of course if you don't mind the handle sitting just outside `#test` you could just leave the height and width at 200 on `#wrapper` and 100% on `#test`.  Or you could find a way to override the css in the jqueryUI.css file.  Either way the handle stays fixed in place quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are testing with the wrong content. The  `!!!!!!!!!!!!...` you have used behaves like a long single word and adds unwanted `scroll`.

It works fine when tested with proper text - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/ayt41bw0/2/

works same way as in the example - https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: If the content overflows the specified div size, i would like it to have a scroll bar. In the link u have specified, the text overflows the container if it is longer.

Comment: when I checked in that jquery ui site, there is no scrollbar added. when width is reduced, even the title 'Resizable' goes outside of the div.

Comment: you can try to add an inner div with overflow